# Finding the Area of a Piecewise Function

Tags: calculus, integration, area

I'm learning applications of integration and this is my first experience with this sort of question. How would I get started on a problem like this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to calculate the integral $\lim_{a\rightarrow1}\int_{0}^{a}2-x^2  dx+\int_{1}^{2} (x-2)^2dx$